# Android: how do I make the value of an integer variable become fixed/permanent in a CardView/RecyclerView?

Tags: android, integer, android-recyclerview

I have an int variable that is shown on a CardView in a RecyclerView list.  The value is shown with a TextView.  Once the value is used to populate the TextView in OnBindViewHolder, how do I freeze/make permanent that value so it does not change the next time onBondViewHolder is run when the next CardView is created?

"cardNumsTotal" is the TextView created in the ViewHolder.

"dblist" is the ArrayList to show the model data in the RecyclerView.

"getCardNum" is the getter of the integer data from a SQLite database.  It is a counter, so CardNum is incremented by +1 each time a new CardView is created for the RecyclerView list.

Below the code, I show a few incorrect examples I am getting and the correct example of what I am trying to achieve.  I have tried setFreezesText(true) on the TextView in the ViewHolder and in OnBindViewholder with no luck.  The current error is that onBindViewHolder is updating all of the TextViews for all of the CardViews with the **current** value of CardNum.  Basically I would like the CardView's TextView to be populated with the value of the CardNum integer **at the time that each individual CardView is created**.  Since CardNum is a counter, I should see CardView #'s being formed in succession: 1,2,3,4,5...  The CardView's are ordered from newest at the top of the RecyclerView list to the oldest.  So if five CardViews have been created I should see Card #5 at the top, then 4,3,2,1.

```
Adapter.java

...
public class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView cardNumstotal;

    public ListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        cardNumstotal = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardNumstotal);
    }
}  

...
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.cardNumstotal.setText(String.valueOf(dbList.get(position).getCardnum()));

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
private boolean updated = false;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ListViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if(updated) return;    
    holder.cardNumstotal.setText(String.valueOf(dbList.get(position).getCardnum()));
    updated = true;

}
```

Comment: Does this mean: if updated then convert to a boolean (that is fixed)?

Comment: Not working.  The TextView's for the prior CardViews are blank.  The TextView for the most recently created CardView is populating correctly.

Comment: I think the boolean above just helps show the current Cardnum total on the TextView but the previous TextViews are ignored.

Comment: I am also trying setFreezesText(true) on the TextView but no luck so far.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood what you were doing.  If the card is getting the wrong value, something must be wrong with `dbList.get(position).getCardnum()`.